# XML organization problems

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I'm having an issue how to organize the XML file to be as the following picture.

I have spent enough time, I couldn't do it. If you could assist me what configuration I should do. There is no restriction on how to organize. but if it is possible to teach me new method instead of parent-child.

I wanted to be like this picture:
[image]

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.ahmed.bluetooth.DataAnalysis">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Peak Pressures"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time in Sec."
        android:layout_weight="1"/>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_Index"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Peaks_index"
        android:textColor="#040307"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Peaks"
        android:textColor="#040307"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_Del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete File"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_margin="1dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The xml is look like this for now, but I want it as the picture:

[image]

Comment: are you need to arrange your components as the first diagram??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Here is the complete solution for your answer**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="#efefef">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Peak Preassure"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Time in sec"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Peak num"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:text="Peak index"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#dddddd">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Empty area for future"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

> **Explanation**
>
> 1. First use a `LinearLayout` of `orientation = vertical`, so that you can put another 2(or more) layouts by dividing the screen vertically (to occupy your `textViews` & your future area)
> 2. Then use `weightSum` attribute in the parent layout & `layoutweight` attribute in chile layouts to define ratios (here I have given 2/5 to upper part & 3/5 to lower part)
> 3. use a `GridLayout` or `Tablelayout` to occupy your elements
> 4. furthermore use attributes like `padding`, `gravity` to improve your UI

Comment: Thank you a lot. It is nice design.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion (with `TableLayout` ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ahmed.bluetooth.DataAnalysis">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Peak Pressures"
                android:layout_column="0" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Time in Sec."
                android:layout_column="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_Del"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delete File"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_column="3" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_Index"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Peaks_index"
                android:textColor="#040307"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_column="0" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Peaks"
                android:textColor="#040307"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_column="1" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Empty area"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```